# Why is A not vertically centered in the cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I had a simple example that worked well but since reinstalling MikTeX, I can't center A in the middle of the cell anymore

```
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.5\textwidth} }

\begin{tabular}{|C|}
    \hline
    A\\[50pt]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: A not vertically centered]

And a MWE more complete :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.45\textwidth} }
\newcolumntype{D}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.45\textwidth} }

\begin{tabular}{|C|D|@{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
    A & B & \\[10pt]
    \hline
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bla
        \item bla
        \item bla
    \end{itemize} &
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f 
    \end{tabular}
 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Something has changed or am I making a mistake somewhere?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you say so: remove `[50pt]` after line terminator. for space around A, you need different approach, for example with use of the `makecell` or `cellspace` package.

Comment: The goal is to draw a table with the first row height is x and the second row height y. The approach you proposed is still relevant ?

Comment: (i) please provide MWE with your table, without it is difficult to imagine, what you like to have, (ii) cells height is mostly determined by cells contents, what should hapen if contents is higher than `x`?

Comment: I've added a MVE in my question. I hope it's a bit clearer ;)

Comment: well, this is only code fragment, not an MWE. Please add `\documentclass`, preamble with necessary packages for table and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry, answer edited !

Comment: `\\[10pt]` should add space *after*  a row. It was a bug that you got your side effect on m-columns. This bug has been corrected some time ago. If you want to enlarge the cells themselves you will now have to use some other code, e.g. an invisible \rule.

Comment: Ok, would you mind to show me how to adjust the height of the first row and keep the content centered vertically and horizontally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reformat your table in the following (however, I'm not sure, what you like to have):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{ragged2e}                           % <---
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}   % <---
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{ >{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname% <---
                        \RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1} } 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,                    % <--- list setup
                      leftmargin=*,
                      label=\textbullet,    
                      before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                      after =\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}
                      }
\begin{tabular}{| L{0.45\linewidth} | L{0.45\linewidth}|}
    \hline
\thead{A}       &   \thead{B}   \\
    \hline
\begin{itemize}
    \item bla
    \item bla
    \item bla
\end{itemize}   &   \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}% <---
                    \begin{tabular}{@{} cc @{}}
                a & b \\
                c & d \\
                e & f
                    \end{tabular}   \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Zarko

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty trick:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{gray!50}
1

2

3 --- --- --- --- ---> 

4

5
\color{black}

\vspace{-5\baselineskip}

\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.45\textwidth}}
\begin{tabular}{|C|C|}
\hline
\rule[-25.5pt]{0em}{60pt}  A & \rule[-25.5pt]{0em}{60pt} B \\
\hline
\begin{itemize}
        \item bla
        \item bla
        \item bla
\end{itemize} & \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f 
\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```